# Need Arduino sketch that only shows maximum temperature

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino temperature probe that works fine showing the current temperature. But I need it to hold onto the maximum temperature and only show that maximum reading after the probe is removed from the hot area. So I'd like to establish the current reading from the previous reading and if the current reading is greater than the previous reading then Serial.print(Temperature); but if the current reading is less than previous reading then there would be no Serial printing of temperature and the reading already showing would remain. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried the greater-than operator?

Comment: I haven't come up with anything to put the greater-than operator between. I just have "Temperature", which is the current temperature. I need something like: If Temperature > previous Temperature then print.

Comment: What is preventing you from storing the previous temperature?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Arduino. I simply do not know how to store the previous temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a sketch like below and reading temperature from a function like `readTemp()`, you need to define a global `maxTemp` variable and check every new temperature value with this variable.

```
int maxTemp;

void setup() {
   maxTemp = -99; //assigning min temp value to make sure new value will take place of this in first comparison.
}

void loop() {
   int newTemp; //This variable will keep new value.
   newTemp = readTemp(); //Read temperature

   if ( newTemp >= maxTemp ) { //Do the comparison, only if greater-than or equal.
       maxTemp = newTemp; //Assign new temperature as maxTemp.
       Serial.print(newTemp); //Write it to serial.
   }

   delay(250); //wait 250ms before another comparison.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Something like this:

```
double maxTemp;

void setup() {
maxTemp = -99; // pre set value that won't be reached(lowest amount)    }

void loop() {
   int newTemp; //This variable will keep new value.
   newTemp = readTemp(); //Read temperature

   if ( newTemp >= maxTemp ) { 
       maxTemp = newTemp; 
       Serial.print(newTemp); 
   }

   delay(1000); 
}
```